# Create a mask for an image with a background

Tags: python, image-processing

I need to enlarge an input image, I don't want to use AI tool LabelMe again so alternatively  I used Microsoft Paint to mask out the unnecessary parts and resize the mask to match original size (of `512 x 512` resolution).

Then I try to create new mask, but I get a wrong mask:

[image]

This is my code:

```
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    
    mask = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    mask = cv2.threshold(mask, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    image[mask != 0] = [255, 255, 255]  
    
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```